# Where to use Task.Run if using a library does not support async await

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous, async-await

I have an application which sends a message over the network, and I would like to perform other work while waiting for the message to be sent and responded to.  I start the messaging process by calling "await SendMessageAsync", which has the following duties:

```
public async Task<bool> SendMessageAsync()
{
    //Do Some Work
    //Send First Message
    //More Work
    //Send Second Message
    //More Work
    //Send Third Message
}
```

If my third party library supported it, I would write it like this:

```
public async Task<bool> SendMessageAsync()
{
     //Do Some Work
     await LibrarySendMessageAsync(firstMessage);
     //More Work
     await LibrarySendMessageAsync(secondMessage);
     //More Work
     await LibrarySendMessageAsync(thirdMessage);
}
```

However SendMessageAsync is not working properly with timeouts.  So I'll need to introduce some parallelism and use Task.Run.

My question is: would it be better to wrap the entire above method in Task.Run, or to wrap each SendMessage method in its own Task.Run?

```
public async Task<bool> SendMessageAsync()
{
     //Do Some Work
     await Task.Run(() => LibrarySendMessage(firstMessage));
     //More Work
     await Task.Run(() => LibrarySendMessage(secondMessage));
     //More Work
     await Task.Run(() => LibrarySendMessage(thirdMessage));
}
```

VS

```
public async Task<bool> SendMessageAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
    //Do Some Work
    LibrarySendMessage(firstMessage);
    //More Work
    LibrarySendMessage(secondMessage);
    //More Work
    LibrarySendMessage(thirdMessage);
    });
}
```

Performance (speed) is very important for this application.  SendMessageAsync will be called repeatedly in a high frequency.

Comment: You really need to profile your code to get a proper answer. Normally I wouldn't imagine it making a significant difference either way but since you are calling it repeadtedly in high frequency then wrapping it in one Task.Run will probably save you overhead from creating Tasks. Profiling your actual code is the way to go in this case since there will be so many factors involved.

Comment: Personally I would do a variation of your 2nd method. Get rid of the Task.Run, rename the function to `SendMessage()` then call it with `var result = await Task.Run(() => SendMessage());`

Comment: Queries to think about:
A single execution of `SendMessageAsync` must be faster Vs A large number of calls to `SendMessageAsync` must be faster
Your method should be "as fast as possible" vs your overall program throughput should be large (scalability)

As you would seen `async` in the C# sense does NOT make your method run faster. It [does not create a new thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Answer (score 3):

Basically your second option... you have a method :-

```
 public async Task<bool> SendMessageAsync()
```

which basically shouldn't be async.  You are saying basically you want the method to be synchronous.... so write that method

```
public bool SendMessage()
{
    //Do Some Work
    LibrarySendMessage(firstMessage);
    //More Work
    LibrarySendMessage(secondMessage);
    //More Work
    LibrarySendMessage(thirdMessage);
}
```

Don't write synchronous code as weird confused async method.  So then if you you want to do that work in a thread then await...

```
await Task.Run(() => SendMessage());
```

which you can wrap into your original method `SendMessageAsync`

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Message received about the readability and breaking it out.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. 
Wrapping the whole thing in a single Task.run is logically simpler to reason with. Once the task is created, the three messages are sent synchronously. synchronous code is always simpler to write, read, and debug

It is more complicated when it comes to performance. In both cases, the 3 messages are sent in an ordered sequence.

Three Task.Runs consume less thread(thread is returned faster to the pool) but will create more tasks as well as incur the cost of transitioning from one task to another. A single task will cause the thread to block longer then necessary. You will need more threads in the thread pool to handle the same amount of messages. You will be balancing the cost of waking up the thread to continue execution and picking a task from the queue to continue execution.

The balance will depend on how long does sending the 3 messages take, how many thread pool thread you can afford to have, what will the expected through put be, and even the pattern of the message arrival(evenly vs sporadic). And, of course, eventually everything depends on profiling.

Comment: Thanks for the response!